# chrome.webstore.install(); Not working on verified site

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

When I attempt to use the chrome.webstore.install(); function on my verified website for my chrome extension, it returns this error

> Installs can only be initiated by the Chrome Web Store item's verified site

Even when the website is the item's verified site.

I do have the link to the item in the head tag:

```
<link rel="chrome-webstore-item" href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/oogdogaijchgbmakknkjcmimfgdpodil">
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How did you get this issue solved. Could you please help. Am struck at the same step with same error.

Answer (score 2):

if you verify ownership for a domain (for example, http://example.com) you can **only** initiate inline installation from any subdomain or page (for example, http://app.example.com or http://example.com/page.html). Check this validation. Having picbox.us is domain verified, you need to make a default page say [picbox.us\index.html](https://picbox.us/index.html) and post all your content there to get chrome inline installation running.

[image]

Comment: The site in which the function is executed is the verified site.  https://picbox.us  (Ignore the WIP icons)

Comment: you extension is on picbox.us so you try all content to picbox.us\index.html etc to get it running. i have updated answer as well

Comment: But why doesn't it allow the install to work if the site you're on is the verified site?  I don't really want to have to add a download page...that's more clicks for the user.

Comment: @KevinSmith: It is functionality of Chrome API, if you feel it is wrong log a bug at http://www.chromium.org/